# What data type is used for IP address in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I created a data table with a column listed with IP address,

```
create table test (id int,name string,ip_adress string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ ;
```

so what data type will I use to define the ip_adress column?
I tried string, binary & array data types, nothing worked.

Comment: String Data type accepts any raw format data, so what is not working here?

Answer (score -1):

use varchar(16)

```
create table test (id int,name string,ip_adress  varchar(16)) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
```

Answer (score -2):

You can specify with String datatype. Below is the example shown to use for IP Address.
[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.